# What does "by what part" mean?

Tags: terminology

I have a homework problem that is asking me for something.  Here's the last line quoted:

> If you switch to the ring, by what part will you decrease the electric field magnitude at P?

Okay, so the only problem that I'm facing is that I'm not sure whether this wants a percentage, or a decimal.  For example, my answer came out to be `0.11`.  Would this be asking for `11%`, or just the decimal like it is right now?

Thanks, and sorry for such a basic question.

---

Edit: the whole question reads like the following:

> Suppose you design an apparatus in which a uniformly charged disk of
>   radius R is to produce an electric field. The field magnitude is most
>   important along the central perpendicular axis of the disk, at a point
>   P at distance 3.10R from the disk (Fig. 22-52a). Cost analysis
>   suggests that you switch to a ring of the same outer radius R but with
>   inner radius R/3.10 (Fig. 22-52b). Assume that the ring will have the
>   same surface charge density as the original disk. If you switch to the
>   ring, by what part will you decrease the electric field magnitude at
>   P?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the rest of the question, just like that, nothing is obvious.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I added it for you.

Comment: Personally, I'd ask the instructor, but if this is not an option, I'd just write both. E.g. `[..] by 0.11, i.e. 11%`.

Comment: @J.D.:  How I wish I could do that.  Unfortunately, the grading system is computerized, so the answer is either right or wrong, no explanations accepted.

Comment: Ops! Good luck then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question suggests that "by what part" means "by what percentage". But then again, context makes this more easy to guess. I would go with the percentage.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I sure do hope you're right.  I only have once chance at getting this problem correct.  If it's wrong, I'm going to come back here and blame you for all my troubles.  Deal?  Just kidding. ;)

Comment: I am not saying that I am right, because I have no means of confirmation :P I'm just saying what I think feels right with what I see.

Comment: I doubt they're going to knock you a mark for putting the percentage if they wanted it in some other form.  You got the right value - I assume - so it shouldn't matter what form you put it in.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: As I said to J.D. above, the system is computerized and will not accept explanations or multiple answers.

Comment: Ops!  Good luck then!

Comment: Yep, just got it wrong.  It ended up being a decimal like my original answer was.  Hopefully I can contact my instructor and show him what I entered.  Accepted for your troubles.